# Web API displaying multiple results for one input value/id

Tags: c#, xml, json, linq, api

I've been following this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api to create my API, and the logic behind it is pretty much the same.

At the moment /api/products gets all products, and GetProduct /api/products/id, gets only 1 product based on the id.

Now my problem is, I'd like to get all products with e.g. ID 1
This is the code used for getting just one product:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (product == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(product);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I understand that you want all products with an Id equal to the id parameter.

It isn't clear what your Ok() method does, so I will leave it there.  You may want to remove it or update it.  Also the name GetProduct suggests a singular result, so you may want to make the method name plural.

This example code gets a list of all products with the given id parameter:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    var product = products.Where(p => p.Id == id).ToList();
    if (product == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(product);
}
```

Comment: 'Ok' method is irrelevant. Thank you, that fixes my problem.